# Combining PubNub Publish/Subscribe with Chat-engine

Tags: chat, pubnub

I want to use [PubNub's](https://www.pubnub.com/) Java client ([publish/subscribe](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/getting-started-guides/pubnub-publish-subscribe)) with a [chat-engine](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/getting-started) Angular client. The only material I could find on how what to accomplish this was this [page in the wiki](https://www.pubnub.com/docs/chat-engine/pubnub-channel-topology) which describes the channel structure. After attempting to subscribe/publish on every combination of their channel structure as synonymous with a direct message, eg: `globalChannel + '#user#' + myUUID + '#write.*'`, I could not get a chat-engine client and a pub/sub client to communicate. Has anyone been able to do this successfully? Is the channel structure actually different? Are their limitations due to the lack of invitations? I have the clients detecting each other's presence, so I can't imagine I'm far.

Comment: What is the value of `globalChannel` var in this case. What is your final literal channel name you are publishing to? If you can enable Java SDK logs, and reproduce, please send those logs to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) and we'll get you some answers. Include this SO link in your support ticket and we'll post final answer back here. We are working on an Android native ChatEngine, too, so this will not be necessary in the future.

Comment: Will do. For everyone, the `globalChannel` is (I believe) always "chat-engine". An example string with trying to 1-1 message someone with a UUID of 12345 would be publishing at `chat-engine#user#12435#write.direct `

Comment: Is the Java client an Android client or a Java server or some other Java platform?

Comment: Java server. I posted my workaround below.

Answer (score 0):

I decided on a workaround. Instead of direct chat, you can create a 2 person private channel with chat-engine (say `channelName`) and can subscribe in java with `"chat-engine#chat#private.#" + channelName`. This isn't direct messaging but should be functionally similar.